# Apache - How to access server from Mobile Network

Tags: android, apache, wamp

I have been working on debugging my android app by connecting my device via usb and connecting it to server by Wi-Fi, with the standard 192.168.1.x as destination

Now I need to spread my app for some "beta testing", but I need to allow connections from outside my router in order to do this.

I read around and find some pieces of advice, and this is the best clue that I get

```
If it's connected to your mobile network, then first find out 
your router external IP address, then forward some port to that 
10.0.2.2:portno and finally you'll be able to see that server from 
your device.
```

Can anyone explain how can I do that?

For example, my router IP is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, my server-pc is 192.168.1.5 and the port used by WAMP is 80

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the configuration on the router itself.

Log in, and go to the section designated `Port Forwarding`. Add a record to forward all port 80 traffic to `192.168.1.5`.